# golang read more 4096 bytes

Tags: file, go

I try read file from TLS connect, but I can read only 4096 bytes (n = 4096). How I can read full file?

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(pc.conn)
msg := make([]byte, 10*1024*1024)
n,err:=reader.Read(msg)
```

Comment: Why can you only read 4096 bytes? What is a "full file" when reading from a stream oriented connection?

Comment: How many bytes are read in one go is up to the Reader implementation. Call Read repeatedly, or use something like io.ReadFull, io.ReadAtLeast, etc. if you want to do it in one call.

Comment: Thank Peter, i will try use io instade of bufio. Jim, I send big file to this socket and when I try read, bufio.reader read only first 4096 bytes (in first call)

Comment: @klynxe: yes, reading from a stream requires multiple calls to `Read`, but you also need to know how to detect what is a "full file", which depends on how you're sending it, and any higher level protocol being used.

Answer (score 1):

`io.Reader.Read(p []byte)` — if succeeds, — is free to return any number of bytes between 1 and `len(p)`; this is by
[its contract](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader):

> Read reads up to `len(p)` bytes into `p`. It returns the number of bytes read (`0 <= n <= len(p)`) and any error encountered. Even if `Read` returns `n < len(p)`, it may use all of p as scratch space during the call. If some data is available but not `len(p)` bytes, *`Read` conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.*

(Emphasis mine.)

The "magic number" 4096 you're observing is likely the size of the cache of some piece of software under your TLS connection.

This actually matches the contract of the [`read(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/read) POSIX syscall
(for sockets, it actually will be [`recv(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/recv) — from "BSD sockets" which every platform supported by Go implements, including Windows; [its counterpart from Winsock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsarecv) has the same semantics, FWIW).

If you *know exactly* how many bytes you need to read from the source, use the [`io.ReadFull`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull) helper.
This is usually the simplest approach to deal with data
encoded in a [TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value)-like format (and [`encoding/binary`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/) helps as well).